# Efficient memcpy function with bit resolution

Tags: bit-manipulation

I need an efficient function to copy a sequence of bits of arbitrary length from an arbitrary position in a packed bit array to another packed bit array. (A bit-by-bit copy won't be good enough and the function is hoped to be fast for small sequences, say 5 to 25 bits in length, but any length should be supported.)

Example:

Copy 12 bits from position 7 in

```
       _ ________ ___
11111000 01000000 01101011 11110110 01100100
```

to position 21 in

```
                       ___ ________ _
11011111 11001010 00000100 11001101 10111111 00101101,
```

yielding

```
                       ___ ________ _
11011111 11001010 00000001 00000001 10111111 00101101.
```

I plan to work with byte/word/doubleword/quadword accesses where possible and beneficial. I am sufficiently familiar with the shifting/bitwise masking techniques to know that this is not trivial and there are many corner cases. So I am looking for a (nearly) ready-made solution, in pseudocode or any language, provided it has been validated.

Any methodological hint to ease this development is welcome.

Comment: I'd align (shl/r) the source data to the dest data, then blend the corners using masks, and the middle bytes with a plain memcpy. A multibyte bit shift shouldn't be too hard to write and it's the only thing you'd need. performance? i don't know! :

Comment: Yes, I know these are the needed ingredients. A multibyte bit shift with partial bytes left and right in the source and in the destination (differently) is a pain in the neck.

Comment: I'd align the sequences so you only have to shift one of them, ideally the source, this way you won't need to re-shift the destinationat the end

Comment: Not possible, there are several sequences to be copied, with arbitrary alignments. Thanks anyway for the suggestions.

Comment: Isn't this what the BitBlt function actually does (monochrome bitmaps)?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia: that's quite right. With a unit image height, it could do the trick. Would be nice if the source code was available, to check efficiency.